# Wanted: list of change lists submitted between 2 labels (perforce)

Tags: perforce

We have a complex source tree with many release branches. A bug was introduced into one of these branches between 2 labels, which can also be equated to change lists. The change list numbers are more than 1000 apart, but most of those change lists will have gone into more active branches. I want a list of all the change lists which went into this branch between the two labels. (My intent is to do the equivalent of "git bisect".)

Imagine that our source tree looks like this:

```
//root/main/...
//root/releaseline1/...
//root/releaseline2/...
//root/releaseline3/... 
etc.
```

I want the set of changelists affecting //root/releaseline17/... between labels rel17_0007 and rel17_0008, where I also know that those labels were applied to all files in //root/releaseline17/...#head at two specific points of time.

A number of variants on `p4 changes -i -l //root/release17/...@rel17_007,rel17_008` have failed, frequently giving me changes made years before label rel17_007.

The information is available from p4v, suggesting that there is an automatable way to answer this question, but I'm failing to find it.

There are enough change lists in the window that I'm not eager to copy the information from p4v (by hand; cut-n-paste doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the correct command to compare the changes between 2 label is

```
p4 diff2 //...@label1 //...@label2
```

To only list the differences :

```
p4 diff2 -Od //...@label1 //...@label2
```

See references:

- [Perforce knowledge base](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3429)
- [p4 diff2 manual](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_diff2.html)

Comment: That gives me the code changes, but how do I get a list of the changelists involved?

Comment: @ArlieStephens: Sorry I misinterpreted you question. Regarding getting the list of change, I am not sure how to do that, maybe look into `p4 integrated` which should give an history from the point of view of changes, and compare the two results ?